# C# WPF MVVM Binding to a Grid but only specific members

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm struggling to figure out how to populate a grid from a  I have in my ModelView.  I have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged.  The best I can do so far is the grid populates the headers only but no data below.  Though that would be nice if I could get that far.  But I really only need to specify a couple of columns to get the results I need.  Description and Barcode.

I can see from MyParts list, there are hundred of items loaded.  Again I only need to see 2 columns not all 50. So far no dice.  Maybe my issue is I don't know what to say in the binding column.  Putting Binding="{Binding Description}" doesn't do anything.  I tried being specific with something like this MyParts.Description.

I should mention I have a button that is being used that does a launches an openfileDialog.  Loads a file and dumps it into part List.  not sure if that matters or not.

```
<Window x:Class="MyCarParts.MainWindow"
        .....
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyCarParts"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MyCarParts.ViewModels" 

        <Window.Resources>
            <viewModel:FileProcessViewModel x:Key="file_vm"></viewModel:FileProcessViewModel>
        </Window.Resources>


         <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource file_vm}, Path=MyParts}" x:Name="gridPartDetails">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Barcode"     IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Not Sure What To Put}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Not Sure What To Put}"/>

        </DataGrid>

<Button x:Name="TaskButton" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource file_vm},Path=FileLoadCommand}" Content="Path"/>
```

```
public class FileProcessViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Part> _MyParts;

    public List<Part> MyParts
    {
        get { return _MyParts; }
        set
        {
            _MyParts = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }
}
```

I have also tried adding this in and changed the Datagrid.  Still nothing.

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:FileProcessViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyParts}" x:Name="MyParts" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Barcode" Binding="{Binding MyParts.Barcode}"/>
```

Comment: Where you you populate `MyParts`?

Comment: I have just one Model View called ViewModels/FileProcessViewModel.cs When I press the button it launches a open file dialog function inside that class and then what it reads each line and adds to to my list called MyParts.  I just use a StreamReader to do this.

Comment: OK, but if you are addiong to the existing list, you need to inform your view. The easiest thing to do is just replace `List<T>` by `ObservableCollection<T>`